# SOQL Find week by day

Tags: apex, soql

I'm looking for an easy way to get a week by day. So that, I have a function that get in input a day, and return all the accounts created in the week of that day.

So for example if I call the function with, as input the day **15th of January 2015**, it get me all accounts created between 12-01-2015 and 18-01-2014 (considering I'm writing dd-mm-yyyy).

Any hints? Is there a declarative way to do it with SOQL similar to `THIS_WEEK` or `LAST_WEEK` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** It appears that you might be after something a bit different.

What you could do is (assuming that your input has been converted to a date) is to find the start of the week for that date and query between it and 7 days in advance.

```
Date startOfWeek = inputDate.toStartOfWeek();
Date endOfWeek = startOfWeek.addDays(7);

List<Account> = [SELECT Name, CreatedDate From Account Where CreatedDate > :startOfWeek AND CreatedDate <= :endOfWeek];
```

[Original Answer For Reference]

Yes, there is a feature of SOQL called 'Date Literals'.
You would perform a query like:

```
List<Account> = [SELECT Name, CreatedDate From Account Where CreatedDate > LAST_N_DAYS:21];
```

There are a lot of other Date Literals that you can use. [Here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) is the full reference.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reference. Maybe I was not so clear, please see the edits.

Comment: No, you were clear enough - my mistake - I've amended my answer :)